# Why wordpress directory slash not present in static home page while present in other pages?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

My javascript is not popping up in my static home page because the forward slash is gone right after the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` even if I have correctly placed it in my functions.php file. Whenever I visit another page of my site, the forward slash is present and the alert popped up in that page. Here is my code.

**Functions.php**

```
<?php

   function custom_javascript(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/custom.js' );
   }

   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_javascript' );
```

**my-static-homepage-page-source** (forward slash is not present)

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://caraga.com/template/wp-content/themes/gwt-wordpress-master-childjs/custom.js?ver=4.1'></script>
```

**my-other-page-page-source** (forward slash is present)

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://caraga.com/template/wp-content/themes/gwt-wordpress-master-child/js/custom.js?ver=4.1'></script>
```

Comment: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` is guaranteed to return a good URI and then you're adding `'/js...'` to it. Looks to me like the issue is somewhere else, not in the `wp_enqueue_script` call.

Comment: I have no clue where I would look for the error

Comment: I'm  guessing a plugin is using the filter inside `wp_enqueue_script` and is altering the generated URL.

Comment: So, the best thing to do is to deactivate the plugins one by one? Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Comment: Do you have an `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', <something> );` in your functions.php file, perhaps rewriting the path?

Comment: Another workaround is using `trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory_uri())` as this will force the slash to be there. It's not perfect but it should fix your problem. Edit: WordPress Codex for that function (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/trailingslashit)

Comment: Yes. Isn't it the code above I just posted?

Comment: I just put a slash inside wp_enqueue_script( 'custom js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri('/') .'/js/custom.js' );

Comment: Perhaps, better and cleaner way: wp_enqueue_script( 'custom js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri('/js/custom.js') );

Comment: Back to my problem again. My site is working weird. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't work